# I cannot build Pythonqt

Tags: python, qt

It is PythonQt : pythonqt.sourceforge.net. I am using PythonQt-1.1 . Qt version 4.6.2 and Python 2.6.4.10 . Visual studio 2008
From instruction:

```
cd PythonQtRoot  
vcvars32  
qmake  
nmake
```

after I typed qmake, it generated makefile, then I entered nmake but it said "makefile(22) :fatal error U1000: syntax error: ')' missing in macro invocation Stop." What did I do wrong here?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Last time I got something like that (years ago) that kind of error was triggered by trying to compile a GPL version of pyqt/qt with Visual Studio: the "free software" version would only compile with mingw32. 

Which version of pyqt are you using? Which version of Qt are you using? Which version of Python? Which version of Visual Studio? What command are you running? What is the exact output?

Comment: Actually it is not pyqt. It is PythonQt : http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/. 

I am using PythonQt-1.1 . Qt version 4.6.2 and Python 2.6.4.10 .

From instruction:  
 > cd PythonQtRoot
 > vcvars32
 > qmake
 > nmake

after I typed qmake, it generated makefile, then I entered nmake but it said "makefile(22) :fatal error U1000: syntax error: ')' missing in macro invocation Stop."

Comment: please edit your question with this information, add information about VisualStudio version.

Comment: thanks for the update. Now, since noone seems to be answering, I suggest asking the question on the pythonqt mailing list (info at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/pythonqt-devel). This is likely a bug in pythonqt.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into similar problems when building other packages with recent releases of Qt on Win32.  I'm running under cygwin, by the way.  After a fair amount of debugging, I discovered that 'qmake' was using the wrong 'mkspec'.  One thing that helped this situation was to force the use of the correct mkspec, like so:

export QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2008
or
export QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc

To find the list of all valid mkspecs, I looked in the directory:
c:\Qt\4.6.0\mkspecs
or
c:\Qt\2010.01\qt\mkspecs

For one particular package, I had some conflicts with other tools installed on my system and had to edit the actual mkspec file to point to the correct tool using an absolute path, but it sounds like that is not your problem here.  It sounds like yours is generating a gmake-compatible Makefile instead of an nmake-compatible Makefile, so this fix should work.

-- Glenn

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to include the PythonQt project as part of your very same project with CMake.

You then simply have to build it as part of your project statically (remove the SHARED from the `add_library` in the base `CMakeLists.txt`, by remembering that if you want it to be so, you have to remove the `project(PythonQt)` from its base `CMakeLists.txt` and then adding to your proper `CMakeLists.txt` base file the following:

```
if( PYTHON_QT_SUPPORT )
    message(STATUS ":::: Including support for PythonQT Shell ::::")
    # Include Python directories
    find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
    include_directories("${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    # Include PythonQt 
    include_directories(YOURPATHTOPYTHONQT/pythonqt/src)
    add_subdirectory(YOURPATHTOPYTHONQT/pythonqt)
endif(PYTHON_QT_SUPPORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to update the Python/Qt versions in the build folder, and include everything you need in your environment?

In build\python.prf:
update python version

Use a Visual Studio Command Prompt and skip the vcvars32.

set your environment paths:

```
set PATH=E:\toolkits\Trolltech\Qt-4.8.6\Win_x64_6.1_v12_debug\lib;%PATH%
set PATH=E:\toolkits\Trolltech\Qt-4.8.6\Win_x64_6.1_v12_debug\bin;%PATH%
set PYTHON_PATH=E:\toolkits\Python\2.7.9\Win_x64_6.1_v12
set PYTHON_LIB=E:\toolkits\Python\2.7.9\Win_x64_6.1_v12\libs
```

In those paths, you should have available:

- all qt libraries (QtCore4.dll, etc.)
- all qt executables (uic, moc, etc)
- python26.dll, python.exe

I've also had to update the other .prf files to make sure the debug extensions are properly done when i'm binding on debug dlls.